# Getting "Cannot allocate memory" when running Puppet agent

Tags: linux, automation, puppet

I'm getting the following errors when I run "puppet agent -t" :

```
Cannot allocate memory - /bin/uname -s
...
Cannot allocate memory - /sbin/arp -an
...
Cannot allocate memory - /bin/uname -s
...
Could not retrieve kernelversion: private method `split' called for nil:NilClass
Could not retrieve kernelmajversion: private method `split' called for nil:NilClass
...
```

The full error is here : http://pastebin.com/fhjqrgBn

When I run the command `/bin/uname -s` manually I get the result whithout any error.

free command shows this :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        609600     160688     448912          0       5716      35432
-/+ buffers/cache:     119540     490060
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Puppet bug ? what do you think ?

Comment: Could you describe your setup more? Is this puppet stand alone, client-server. What version of puppet, which OS

Comment: I'm getting pretty much the same errors. Did you ever resolve this? My setup is a bit complicated -- but do you have any insight into this problem in retrospect?

Comment: Update: Ran this a 4th time, while I was logged out of the machines this time, and I didn't get the error. Still not sure what it was about.

Comment: @gabe Haven't had the problem since i've upgraded my puppet master instance from an EC2 t1.micro to m1.small. http://aws.amazon.com/en/ec2/instance-types/#instance-details

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your system is running out of memory. Check your memory usage with free, -m displays values in MB:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           590        412        177          0         22        314
-/+ buffers/cache:         75        514
Swap:            0          0          0
```

From a different shell you can check memory usage with free while puppet agent is running or use another utility like top or dstat.

Try looking at your service status, make sure there are no services running that you don't need:

```
service --status-all
```